# Not getting progress towards dungeon level achievements

Tags: steam, achievements, torchlight

After completing the main quest in torchlight (after level 34 of the mine), the player can continue in another dungeon. I'm well past level 60 in that second dungeon, but I never got the "Deep Delver" achievement for reaching the 50th floor of a dungeon. I checked the progress, and it shows 34/50 - as though the achievement hasn't been acknowledging my progress through the new dungeon. I noticed the same for the "True Delver" achievement - it's stuck on 34/100. Any thoughts?

---

**Update**

For the record, I ended up getting past this. It turns out Torchlight was keeping track of my dungeon level, but the steam achievement progress bar needed to be manually refreshed. In addition to this, I noticed a few things about achievements in torchlight. First, almost all achievements only update their progress when loading a level - so if you've been sitting in one spot selling items, smashing barrels, or fishing, and the progress counter isn't updating, don't fret - simply walk through a portal and when you get to the other side, you should be able to refresh the achievements and see your progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Torchlight achievements are generally buggy. I had quite a few problems with them myself, most of the time exactly like you describe it - a counter stopped working. (In my case it was for sold items and killed trolls, if I recall correctly.)

So you're not alone (look e.g. [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=18426343)), and there probably isn't much you can do. :(

**Edit**: It just occured to me: saving achievements doesn't seem to work when you're offline. But somehow I presumed that would not be your case.

Comment: I just recalled a particularly nasty one: my friend did a fastrun of the game in about 5 hours, and didn't get the achievement. That was reason enough for him to stop playing the game, and I'm hardly surprised. (I got that one with no problems.)

Comment: LAME. Any evidence that starting a new character or wiping the installation will get them working again? I have a weird OCD about leaving a ton of achievements half completed.

Comment: I know how you feel, but I doubt it would help. Maybe it would, but then it might just break some others. Sometimes I spend a little too much time completing achievements, but many of those in Torchlight just aren't worth it. (E.g. the one for selling 10 000 items doesn't include those you sold via your pet, so it would take forever to get; even more so if you encounter a bug.)

Comment: Update - I guess I was a little confused as to how achievement tracking worked. I got my 100% in this game. Mind you, I ended up writing two macros. After beating the game 5 times, I still only had about 1000 item sales, so I used my richest character and had a macro continuously buy and sell the cheapest potion to get the one for selling 10,000 items. I then wrote a rather complex macro to perform fishing for me, since I'd only gotten about 120 and needed 1000. That one had to run about 8 hours. Can't imagine doing that manually (let alone enjoying it).

Comment: Care to share? What are they written in? (Are they Torchlight mods/macros? I never looked into that.)

Comment: I threw an answer into this existing question: [Fishing is boring, how can I fish faster?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/fishing-is-boring-how-can-i-fish-faster), I thought it was a more fitting place for my macro strategy. Enjoy!