# What is the easiest/quickest way to get fish?

Tags: torchlight

I keep running out of fish to feed my doggie. Fishing holes are few and far between and usually halfway through a level which I have to clear of enemies first.

I'm looking for the quickest way to get fish. If there is a vendor somewhere, great! I have lots of money and am willing to part with it. If not, which is the most accessible fishing hole? Is there one anywhere near a Waygate, to minimise travel time?

Comment: Not sure that there is a certain level someone can give you. Pretty sure the dungeons are random.

Comment: See also: [Fishing is boring, how can I fish faster?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/fishing-is-boring-how-can-i-fish-faster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fishing hole directly in town. However, as Loren Pechtel [mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79553/what-is-the-easiest-quickest-way-to-get-fish/79555#comment109922_79555), you will most likely only get small fish there.

Since the dungeons themselves are randomized, you will have to take notes for yourself on which levels you found a fishing hole or merchant, I don't know for sure whether they will remain there throughout the entire game though.

Answer (score 3):

You realize a fishing hole doesn't give just one fish?  You can keep on fishing if you want.

Comment: Don't forget to mention there is a fishing hole directly in town..

Comment: @Zommuter: Isn't that one quite limited in the level of fish it can give, though?  I thought you had to be level 19 or deeper to get the best fish.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I think you're right, but at least for the start it is a place to come back to regularly.